# I want to take a decision on two gaussian distributions, what approach can I take?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, sample-size, inference

I observe a one dimensional random source, which could be any of two Gaussian distributions with a different set of parameters that do not change over time. They have a the same variance and a slightly different median (plus or minus 5%).

I can ask for as many points of data as I want, however I want to be able to recognize the distribution as fast as possible (that is, with as little observations as possible). A simple threshold on one observation is not good enough, since both distributions overlap significantly.

1. This problem is probably very common, what is the name for it?
2. What is a standard approach to solve this?

Comment: I answered, but it occurs to me that I may have misinterpreted your question.  Clarification: is the situation that your point source is one *or the other* Gaussian, but not both, you know the means and variances already, and you want to know with respect to what Gaussian your point source is coming from?  This isn't what my brain heard the first time I read, possibly I read what I was expecting to hear.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply ! Yes, the source is one or the other. I can't be both. The source doesn't change.

Comment: Ok then, I'll remove my answer for now, sorry about that. Quick follow up: It seems evident (though I haven't attempted to sketch a proof) that the best estimator would be to calculate the mean of your sample , determine which of the two known means is closest, and then choose the Gaussian associated with that closest mean (in the equal variance case).  What's probably interesting though, is to have some handle on how much data you need for this estimate to be "good".  Is this right?

Comment: Exactly :-) I want to have a way to calculate after how many points I can be certain of the nature of the source. Calculating the mean would be enough ?
What to do with it then, see when it crosses a threshold ?

Comment: I think this is most fruitfully cast as a Bayesian decision problem

Comment: Are you sure ? Because the source will always produce 100% of A, or 100% of B. Not sometimes A, sometimes B.

Comment: I think @Glen_b is correct.  If you had a prior belief that the points were coming from $A$ or $B$, you could use the probability calculation below along with bayes rule to update to a posterior belief.

Comment: Taiko I don't see why that's an issue; the Bayesian decision being made would yield one of the two (i.e. would pick the option that minimizes the loss for whatever loss function you use). Even if you skipped the decision-theory and just compute the posterior, it would be the posterior probability of "100% A", not "the proportion of A". You would then look at the relative sizes of the posterior probabilities (and if you wish, weigh those against the relative costs of the two wrong choices, taking you back toward a decision-theoretic framework).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's call the two Gaussians $G_0$ and $G_1$, their known means $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1$, and their common variance $\sigma^2$.  We may as well assume that $\mu_0 < \mu_1$ and that the data is coming from $G_0$, because the situation is totally symmetric.

Here's the decision precoedure:

- Calculate the mean of the sample $\hat{\mu}$.
- Calculate the distance from $\hat{\mu}$ to $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1$.
- If the sample mean is closer to $\mu_0$, choose $G_0$, otherwise choose $G_1$.

To estimate how often we choose incorrectly, let's say we have $N$ data points.  Then the [sampling distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_distribution) of $\mu_0$ is:

$$ \hat{\mu_0} \sim N \left( \mu_0, \frac{\sigma}{N} \right) $$

We make the *wrong* choice when:

$$ \hat{\mu_0} > \frac{1}{2} \left( \mu_0 + \mu_1 \right) $$

We can calculate the probability (taken with respect to the sampling distribution) of this event as:

$$ Pr \left( \hat{\mu_0} > \frac{1}{2} (\mu_0 + \mu_1) \right)
   = Pr \left( x \sim N \left( 0, \frac{\sigma}{N} \right) > \frac{1}{2} (\mu_1 - \mu_0) \right) $$

Everything in this final equation is known, so given a pre-specified error rate, you can back into how much data you need.

Comment: Say, in another setting, their variance is different as well. Is there a standard approach to differentiate them ?

Comment: That complicates things, but the basic framework should get you through.  1) the decision boundary is no longer $\frac{1}{2}(\mu_0 + \mu_1)$, but some other convex combination of the two means.  2) You can't rely on symmetry anymore, so you have to analyze both cases (truly coming from $G_0$ and truly coming from $G_1$) separately, and you'll need some apriori estimate of how likely it is that the true distribution is $G_0$ rather than $G_1$.  Give it a shot, if you're stuck tomorrow I'll try to help out.